# SQL Server: CURRENT_USER, SYSTEM_USER, SESSION_USER

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the difference between these? They all sound the same to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System_user -> the current windows user

Current_user ->  Current SQL server User

Session_user ->  returns the user name of the current context in the current database